# How to properly display a specific records with datatable using PHP

Tags: php

I am working with **datatable** and the code can successfully display the entire records. searching of records is also working.

I am trying to display a specific record when page loads. you can see that `SELECT * FROM users` will display all records at once. I need to display a specific record when page loads like `SELECT * FROM users where id=$userid and email=$email`.

In normal PDO query I can just do

```
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where email=:email and id=:id");
$result->execute(array(':email' => $email,':id' => $userid));
```

Here in the datatable is a little bit complicated.

Where do I add something like

```
$sql .= 'WHERE id = '.$userid.' and email = '.$email.' ';
```

Here is the full  code for datatable backend:

```
<?php 


include('db.php');

if(isset($_POST["get_content"])){
$get_content = strip_tags($_POST["get_content"]);
if($get_content == 'get_data'){


$userid =102;
$email = 'test@gmail.com';


$sql= '';
$error = '';
$message='';
$response= array();

$sql .= "SELECT * FROM users ";
if(isset($_POST["search"]["value"])){

$value= $_POST["search"]["value"];
$sql.= 'WHERE fullname LIKE "%'.$value.'%" ';
$sql .= 'OR email LIKE "%'.$value.'%" ';

  }

$start = $_POST['start'];
$length = $_POST['length'];
$draw= $_POST["draw"];

if(isset($_POST["order"])){
$order_column = $_POST['order']['0']['column'];
$order_dir = $_POST['order']['0']['dir'];


//$sql .= 'WHERE id '.$userid.' ';
$sql .= 'ORDER BY '.$order_column.' '.$order_dir.' ';
}
else{

$sql.= 'ORDER BY id DESC ';
}
if($length != -1){
$sql .= 'LIMIT ' . $start . ', ' . $length;
}

$pstmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$pstmt->execute();
$rows_count = $pstmt->rowCount();

while($row = $pstmt->fetch()){
$rows = array();
$rows[] =  $row['id'];
$rows[] = $row['fullname'];
$rows[] =  $row['email'];

$response[] = $rows;
}

$data = array(
"draw"    => $draw,
"recordsTotal"  => $rows_count,
"data"    => $response);
}



 echo json_encode($data);
}
    

?>
```

Comment: What is the problem? if i am not wrong might be you have problem between repeating `where` keyword when search happen, am i right?

Comment: Thanks for responding, the issue is not keyword search. Am trying to display a specific record when page loads. you can see that `SELECT * FROM users` will display all records at once. I need to display a specific record when page load like `SELECT * FROM users where id=anyid and email=anymail`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, you need manage to put `WHERE` condition for `id, email` in your example code,

Do change some portion of your code:

```php
$sql .= "SELECT * FROM users ";

// ADD YOUR REQUIREMENT CONDITION
$sql .= 'WHERE id = '.$userid.' and email = '.$email.' ';

if (isset($_POST["search"]["value"])){

    $value = $_POST["search"]["value"];
    
    // CHANGED WHERE TO AND
    $sql .= 'AND (fullname LIKE "%'.$value.'%" ';
    $sql .= 'OR email LIKE "%'.$value.'%") ';

}
```

Comment: Thanks.  in addition, you will need to bracket the like query as per  below `

$sql.= 'AND (fullname LIKE "%'.$value.'%" OR email LIKE "%'.$value.'%") ';`